# How to detect failure/error in a test report/log in QTP

Tags: report, reporting, automated-tests, qtp

In QTP, I often report back to the log whenever critical parts of a test either pass or fail. I use the method: `Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "Critical Area of Test", "Things went better than expected"`

I would like to detect whether there have been any errors logged to the report by the time I finish the test. The errors I'm looking at aren't anything like `Err.Raise InvalidCall`; an error would just be anytime I call `micFail`. By knowing if (and where) a micFail has been called in the test, I could then have a custom function automatically write the results to different areas.

Is it possible to create a function that looks in the default reports to see if the test failed, and if so, which area?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `micFail` with a custom function that sets an environment variable, and report on that environment variable at a later time.

The custom function would be defined as follows:

```
Function OnFail()
  Environment.Value("Status") = "FAIL"
  OnFail = micFail
End Function
```

So every time you would normally use `micFail`, use `OnFail`:

```
Reporter.ReportEvent OnFail, "Subject", "Description"
```

And at the end of the test, check the environment variable and perform the actions desired:

```
In Environment.Value("Status") = "FAIL"
  ' ...
End If
```

Alternatively, you could create a function that replaces `Reporter.ReportEvent` (it would accept the same parameters and call `Reporter.ReportEvent`). In this function, you would check the status parameter and perform additional logic based on `micFail`.